# AWS iot policy still allow other topics to access via mqtt

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, iot, aws-iot

I am trying to allow only those topics to be used during subscribe and publish via mqtt in aws iot core which are specified in aws inline iot policy. But it looks like it allows other topics as well.

For e.g this shouldn't work
mytopic/test/test-123/publish123 (but its working) as publish123 is not specified

Below is an inline policy

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iot:Connect"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:eu-central-1:123456789:client/${iot:Certificate.Subject.CommonName}"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iot:Subscribe"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iot:eu-central-1:123456789:topicfilter/mytopic/test/${iot:Certificate.Subject.CommonName}/subsricption",
        "arn:aws:iot:eu-central-1:123456789:topicfilter/mytopic/test/+/+/+/subsricption"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iot:Receive"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:eu-central-1:123456789:topic/io/ksb/m2c/${iot:Certificate.Subject.CommonName}/*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iot:Publish"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iot:eu-central-1:123456789:topic/mytopic/test/${iot:Certificate.Subject.CommonName}/publish1",
        "arn:aws:iot:eu-central-1:123456789:topic/mytopic/test/${iot:Certificate.Subject.CommonName}/publish2",
        "arn:aws:iot:eu-central-1:123456789:topic/mytopic/test/+/+/+/publish2",
        "arn:aws:iot:eu-central-1:123456789:topic/mytopic/test/${iot:Certificate.Subject.CommonName}/subsricption",
        "arn:aws:iot:eu-central-1:123456789:topic/mytopic/test/+/+/+/subsricption"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: How are you testing the publish? Is it possible your policy isn't being used? Perhaps try explicitly changing the `Effect` on the `iot:Publish` to `Deny` to confirm.

Comment: @BenT I am using mosquitto mqtt to publish. By replacing Deny it is working. But not with Allow

Comment: @BenT By replacing Deny now it is denying for all topics, it seems like * is been working instead of applied topics in the resources

Comment: By any chance does your certificate's Subject.CommonName have an * in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MQTT wildcards are only supported in topic filters (`topicFilter` instead of `topic`). Topic filters are used in the `subscribe` part of the policy only.

This means that the publish part of the policy needs to be more prescriptive in listing topics and `+` or `#` cannot be used. The topic resource allows you to use a `*` wildcard as per IAM usage. This works like a greedy `.*` regular expression when matching.

Comment: Thank you. But I am not using any wildcards in subscribe and publish. It was just an assumption that If I define the Deny it shows an error in all topics even I have specified the topics same goes by specifying the Allow

Comment: The topic entries like `"arn:aws:iot:eu-central-1:123456789:topic/mytopic/test/+/+/+/publish2"` have the `+` wildcard. These aren't supported for publishing.

Comment: Can you also enable IoT core logging and dump the relevant log entries from cloudwatch? Do this for both the Allow and Deny case. This will help diagnose the issue.

Comment: The policy is working fine now. used qos:1 to check further and yes + is not supported. Thank you

Comment: is there is a way to make it more restrictive while publishing? for now instead of + I have used *

Comment: You can have both `Allow` and `Deny` on different topics in the same policy. But ultimately you may need to restrict your topics and/or change the topic hierarchy to work around the how you can implement your policy.

Comment: I will check what I can now do it with it but seems ok for me now. Thank you for your support